# Emailing PAN securely?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope

Has anyone successfully implemented a PCI approved method of emailing PAN data? I know there are concerns managing all the PCI requirements in an email solution but is there anyone that has actually satisfied all PCI 3.2 requirements and had this approved by their QSA?

Comment: this may be helpful http://blog.securitymetrics.com/2015/06/is-it-safe-to-email-credit-card-information.html

Answer (score 2):

If you solicit PAN data via email, it's likely easier to provide the corresponding person a HTTPS interface through which they can communicate their PAN via text boxes. You can then control how submission works such that you can securely encrypt and store the data on receipt.

If you solicit files containing PAN, it's probably easier to use an SFTP server.

You could request that the person add the PAN to a file attachment. The person could encrypt the file using a random password (which would use a Password Based Key Derivation Function) and encrypt the file using an AES 256-bit key. The password used could then be communicated via a separate communications channel.

You could use PGP/GPG email encryption if you and the correspondent have this available.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortuantely our business model and clients desire continuing to use Email while we are working towards PCI so these other channels are not an option at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate which direction your email is going (in or out) in the questions.  Lets take each one in order.

IN

You can't stop customers from doing this. You can stop requesting it and putting up warning and notices that the email will be rejected on your web site.  And you can clearly state this in your policies and processes.

However, if your customer sends you email with PAN data you should reject it.  The PCI DSS is very clear you CANNOT store PAN data in the clear.  Accepting any PAN and auth data (CVV2,...) would clearly violate PCI DSS as the emails are stored in the clear on the email servers and maybe on the email clients.  Also you have the whole issue of NOT being able to protecte the exchange of CHD in the clear over the Internet.

If you are unable to reject the mail based on MOD10 check of numeric strings, then your only choice is to remove the PAN in the reply and delete the email from your system.  This should be documented in your process for handling support/sales cases.  If your sales people are doing this, stop them now.  Better to have the customer call and give you CHD for MOTO calls acceptance or send via FAX.  Instruct your customers to NEVER send CHD to you via email on your web site.

OUT

If you are sending emails out with PAN data in the clear -- STOP!  You should not be doing this.  See above.  If you need to send PAN data out via email for some strange reason, you need to encrypt the PAN data with AES then attach it to the email and send it.  The keys should be exchanged via SMS or voice to decrypt or use PKI.

Generally speaking, using email to exchange CHD is just a bad idea.  There are other solutions -- phone, secure web pages, FAX, SFTP.